# How to get id in button list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Index file:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <button id="@item.id" class="btn btn-info" onclick="UpdateStatus(this.id)">Update status</button>
}
```

and I also have this JavaScript function:

```
function UpdateStatus(id) {
    //var id = this.id;//$(this).attr('id');// this not work 
    $("#".id).attr("disabled","disabled");                      

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Comment/UpdateStatus",
        data: { id: id },
        type: "POST",
        success:function (data) {                    
            bootbox.alert("Cập nhật status thành công!");
        },
        error:function (e) {
            bootbox.alert(e.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I get the Id with `$("#".id).attr("disabled","disabled");`?

Comment: `.` is to concatenate strings in PHP, not in JavaScript. It's `+` in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ionut - I assume they're trying to disable the button, not query for a disabled button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$("#" + id).prop('disabled', true);`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function UpdateStatus(id) {
                $("#" + id).prop('disabled', true);                     

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Admin/Comment/UpdateStatus",
                    data: { id: id },
                    type: "POST",
                    success:function (data) {                    
                        bootbox.alert("Cập nhật status thành công!");
                    },
                    error:function (e) {
                        bootbox.alert(e.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You should change `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` to `.prop('disabled', true)`. While this works, semantically speaking `disabled` is a property not an attribute...

Comment: I'm a beginner. Thanks to you that i do good